# How to get Proper APA referencing format

Tags: cross-referencing, apa-style

I'm trying to use reference in apa format for my report.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{report}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\chapter{Intro}

A traditional professional asset management firms 
are organized in two basic ways \cite{book:SAPM}
.....blah..blah....

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

My bib file looks like

```
@book{ book:SAPM,
           author = "{Frank  Reily, Keith Brown}",
           title = "Analysis of Investments and Management of Portfolios",
           publisher = "CENGAGE Learning",
           year = "2012"
 }
```

My output is...

> References
>
> Frank Reily, Keith Brown. (2012). Analysis of investments and
>   management of portfolios. CENGAGE Learning.

Also at the citation sentence in the paragraph it is showing like this...

> A traditional professional asset management firms are organized in two
>   basic ways[]

The desired output should be...

> Bibliography
>
> Reily F.,Brown K. (2012). "Analysis of investments and management of
>   portfolios", CENGAGE Leraning.

At the citation sentence in the paragraph, it should be like....

> A traditional professional asset management firms are organized in two
>   basic ways (Riely, Brown, 2012).

I'm a beginner. So, kindly explain in detail. Also I think there is some problem with my aux and bbl files. Some times I have to delete these files for the pdflatex to run.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you follow the compile sequence: (pdf)LaTeX > BibTeX > (pdf)LaTeX?

Comment: Werner is right, this looks like lack of *compilations*

Comment: Is the `author` field correct as stated? I believe it should be stated as `author = "Frank K. Reilly and Keith C. Brown",`. I.e., don't insert a comma between authors; instead, use the keyword `and`.  Let BibTeX and the chosen bibliography style handle the chores of whether and how to abbreviate first names and how to generate citation callouts.

Comment: Note that you use `"{Frank  Reily, Keith Brown}"`.  This is the equivalent of `{{Frank  Reily, Keith Brown}}`, where the inner set of braces prevents -- by design -- BibTeX from doing anything to the contents.  Mico's suggestion therefore stands. (Note how he has only used the 'outer' set.)

Comment: @Mico Thank you mate. It worked.But the citation callout at the paragraph is still showing like "[]" , like I mentioned above.Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @Sujith - Please see my answer: I am unable to reproduce the problem you report.

Comment: Your desired output is not APA-style formatted...

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

I'm afraid I'm unable to reproduce the error you report getting. After running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on the MWE (minimum working example) below, in which I've specified

```
author = "Frank K. Reilly and Keith C. Brown",
```

instead of your

```
author = "{Frank  Reily, Keith Brown}",
```

I get the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}
@book{ book:SAPM,
  author = "Frank K. Reilly and Keith C. Brown",
  title  = "Analysis of Investments and Management of Portfolios",
  publisher = "CENGAGE Learning",
  year = "2012",
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
A traditional professional asset management firms 
are organized in two basic ways \cite{book:SAPM}.
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Note that the appearance of the reference and of the citation callout is governed by the choice of bibliography style (here: `apacite`). If that's not the look you're looking for (pun intended...), you should probably use a different bibliography style.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May be, like some one mentioned above, it  is compilation sequence problem after all. You say, pdf latex>bibtex>pdflatex. I have two files. Which is main report as Report.tex and other file is reference file ref.bib Now, can you please tell me how to get the compilation sequence pdflatex>bibtex>pdflatex. I'm a beginner,I don't understand the compilation sequence. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: @Sujith - If the main file is named `report.tex`, you would need to type `pdflatex report`, `bibtex report`, `pdflatex report`, and `pdflatex report` yet again.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, type where?